# jQuery ID selector hack / workaround?

Tags: jquery

I have a friend whose site is using Joomla with various modules / plugins. What he wanted was for any prices that matched a certain sum to be replaced with POA however, the Joomla plugin he uses spits out id's for the price so jQuery would only find the first instance and not change the rest to POA too. As a workaround I used a class selector which was essentially a container for each product:

```
    $('.vehiclelist_right:contains("1,000,000")').html($('.vehiclelist_right:contains("1,000,000")').html().replace('1,000,000', 'POA'));
$("span#auto_maintitle_price").css("visibility", "visible");
```

and this worked great, in the CSS we hid the prices then use jQuery to unhide them once the page loaded to avoid the £1,000,000 being shown to customers. Now, since changing to the class selector the price doesnt unhide on the individual pages (once you click into a product) like it did when using the old code:

```
$('#auto_maintitle_price').html($('#auto_maintitle_price').html().replace('1,000,000', 'POA'));
         $("span#auto_maintitle_price").css("visibility", "visible");
```

it stays as visibility: hidden;
does anyone have any bright ideas / hacks /workarounds?

Comment: the second sample, with using IDs you're providing "$('#auto_maintitle_price').html($('#auto_maintitle_price').html().re..." doesn't work correctly?

Comment: it does but only for the first id on the stock page (there is multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id selector that you're using in second example `$("span#auto_maintitle_price")`
will only elect the first item in the list if you have several `<span>` tags with `auto_maintitle_price` id.

You should still use classes for similar elements, or use `$.each` to iterate over all of them like this:

```
$("span#auto_maintitle_price").each(function(){
  // $(this) - is now each of the items
  var initialValue = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(initialValue.replace('1,000,000', 'POA')).css("visibility", "visible");
})
```

Comment: I don't have a choice to use classes it is what the plugin he uses spits out code wise...

Comment: strangely has no effect (doesn't chnage to POA nor does the css get changed to visible. Console shows: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function

Comment: cracked it! Thank you.